# How can I fix my code? 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a 2D array using the user's input and the creating random numbers in the second line.
E.g:

Output should be:

If the user enters "7" then:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 (User's input)
>
> 0 2 4 8 9 8 5  (Random numbers)

but instead I only get one random number.

My code is working but I can't see to create the array correctly. 
My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {



        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of exits: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();

        int [][] A = new int[2][n];
        for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
                  A[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(A[1][n-1]);
        System.out.print("Distance between exit i and exit j is: " + distance());
    }



    public static int distance(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter exit i: ");
        int i = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter exit j: ");
        int j = input.nextInt();
        return i + j;
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want the output to be something like in the example but I don't get to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this help?

```
    int n = input.nextInt();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int [][] A = new int[2][n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
       A[0][i] = i+1;
       A[1][i] = rand.nextInt(10);
    }
```

Comment: I haven't use Random before. Is it the same as Math.random?

Comment: Also do I need to create a variable to make it work? Because I am getting an error.

Comment: Random here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

It's psuedo-random, though it can work for small projects.  :)

Comment: `Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()); int randNumber = r.nextInt(10);`

Comment: Now, to be fair, storing an array with numbers from 1...N is pretty useless, but I wanted to give you a straight answer. You are likely to be able to produce the number doing i+1 (no storage) in whatever place you iterate over the array.

Answer (score 0):

Am not too certain about what you mean by: 
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 (User's input) 
    0 2 4 8 9 8 5 (Random numbers) 
Do you want users to manually enter "1 2 3 4 5 6 7"?

Eitherway, here's something to help with the printing aspect:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of exits: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    int [][] A = new int[2][n];
    for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
              A[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*10);
        }
    }

    for(int[] b: A)
    {
        for(int k: b)
        {
            System.out.print(k + " ");       
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print("Distance between exit i and exit j is: " + distance());
}
```